# Painting the chessboard symmetrically

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, coloring, chessboard

We are asked to find all natural numbers $n$ for which we can paint the cells of a $2n \times 2n$ chessboard black and white such that:

1. each pair of cells symmetric about the center of the board consists of two different colored cells;
2. each row/column has exactly $n$ black and $n$ white cells.

Claim: the answer is all even $n$, because as I have observed

1. for even $n$ we can paint the upper half of the board in a standard way and then reflect it about the center of the board and that (hopefully) will get us the right coloring. I need help proving the construction works for even $n$.
2. for odd $n$ this construction fails, however it gives us a hint, because if we say we have $k_1$ black cells in the upper half of the first column and $k_{2n}$ black cells in the upper half of the last column then by symmetry $k_1 + (n - k_{2n}) = n$, so $k_1 = k_{2n}$, but this is impossible as by symmetry $k_1 = n - k_{2n}$. Is it sufficient?

Comment: In the odd case, how do you conclude $k_1 = n - k_{2n}$?

Comment: You can probably get through by counting black squares in "upper right and left quadrant" rather than "upper halves of first and last column". That will give you $k_{UL}+k_{UR}=n^2$ as well as $k_{UL} + (n^2-k_{UR}) = n^2$.

Comment: @Troposphere this is nice but I think very similar to my approach

Comment: Yes, that was an proposal for how to modify your approach to repair the problem @aschepler pointed out.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, what do you mean exactly by the "upper half" of a column?

Comment: @rogerl: The side length of the board is $2n$.

Comment: I agree with aschepler that you can't conclude $ k_1 = n - k_{2n}$. $\quad $ In particular, you haven't used the condition that "each row has exactly $n$ black cells". Since we can find a configuration where each column has $n$ black cells, and the board is colored per condition 1, this implies that your proof cannot be correct. $\quad$ Tropo's comment fixes this error (where do they use the condition on rows?)

Answer (score 1):

To prove it is impossible for odd $n$, let $q_1,q_2,q_3$ and $q_4$ be the number of black squares in each quadrant of the board, with the indices chosen so $q_{i+1}$ and $q_i$ refer to adjacent quadrants, for each $i\in \{1,2,3\}$. The conditions on row sums and column sums imply
$$
q_1+q_2=q_2+q_3=q_3+q_4=q_4+q_1=n^2 
$$
Furthermore, the symmetry condition implies
$$
q_1+q_3=q_2+q_4=n^2
$$
These equations combine to prove that each $q_i=n^2/2$, which is a contradiction.